# Xcode Preview not working due to noExecutablePath for WindowsAzureMessaging

Tags: xcode, swiftui, azure-notificationhub

xcode Preview is not working and I am getting this error:

> HumanReadableSwiftError
>
> SettingsError:
> noExecutablePath(IDESwiftPackageStaticLibraryProductBuildable:ObjectIdentifier(0x0000600002fa6370):'WindowsAzureMessaging')

Has anybody run into this before? It is running in the simulator.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a specific SDK or Package?

Comment: WindowsAzureMessaging for NotificationHub

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Bugsee, and it looks like some other people are having this issue too. I'd recommend following this thread on the Apple developer forums, it sounds like Apple is hoping to have it fixed in Xcode 14.1 https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707569